# How can I run three tasks with parameters in sequence?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have this code so far:

```
gulp.task('make_prod_aa', function () {
    makeAppHtml(config.srcAalHtml, function () {
        runSequence(
          'makeTemplate',
          'make_css_bundle',
          'rename_css_bundle',
          'make_js_bundle',
          'rename_js_bundle',
          function () {
              makeAppIndex('index-aa.html');
          });
    });
});
```

It allows me to pass parameters into two functions and runs the functions and the tasks all in order.  Now I would like to pass parameters into a third task. I want to be able to pass the `config.aaTemplates` parameter to the task makeTemplate which is here:

```
gulp.task('makeTemplate', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.aaTemplates)
          .pipe(print(function (file) {
              return "Added file " + file + " to template";
          }))
       .pipe(minifyHTML({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
       .pipe(templateCache({ standalone: true, root: '/app' }))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(config.destPartials))
       .pipe(gzip(gzip_options))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(config.destPartials));
});
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on how I can do this.

Comment: Just apply the exact same refactoring that I described to you in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644578#36651822) to your `makeTemplate` task. Of course, if you do that with every task in your `runSequence()` you will eventually just end up with lots of nested callbacks, aka [callback hell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098066/). At that point its probably best to look into something like [`async.waterfall()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is another option than using JS closure to have all tasks which run in a sequence sharing the same config. [Proof](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence/blob/master/index.js#L88)

For example:

```
var config = require('path/to/config');

function makAppAppHtml () {
        runSequence(
          'makeTemplate',
          'make_css_bundle',
          'rename_css_bundle',
          'make_js_bundle',
          'rename_js_bundle',
          function () {
              makeAppIndex('index-aa.html');
          });
}

function makeTemplate () {
    return gulp.src(config.aaTemplates)
            .pipe(print(function (file) {
                return "Added file " + file + " to template";
            }))
         .pipe(minifyHTML({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
         .pipe(templateCache({ standalone: true, root: '/app' }))
         .pipe(gulp.dest(config.destPartials))
         .pipe(gzip(gzip_options))
         .pipe(gulp.dest(config.destPartials));
  });
}

gulp.task('make_prod_aa', makAppAppHtml);
gulp.task('makeTemplate', makeTemplate);
```

Both `makeAppHtml` and `makeTemplate` have access to config object because it was defined in the outer scope, the same trick could be applied to the function scope, for more detailed example I recommend [JavaScript Garden article](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures).

Comment: can you explain about JS closure.  I heard people talking about Closure but don't know anything about it.  If you could give an example that would be really good. Thank you.